# How to resolve issue of circular definition for an `If` statement

Tags: programming-languages

I am trying to define an `If` statement, but am stuck because the definition/implementation of `If` is circular from what I have tried. For example, here is one definition:

```
class If {
  provide: Condition
  provide: TrueBlock
  body:
    If (Condition) {
      call(TrueBlock)
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
If (true) {
  Something()
}
```

But the thing is, the definition itself uses `If` to define it:

```
class If {
  ...
    If (Condition) {
      call(TrueBlock)
    }
}
```

The only other way I can think of defining it is by saying that an `If` statement is an "atomic statement", and so it doesn't have an implementation. (The compiler or whatever would then have special instructions to treat it uniquely).

```
class If {
  provide: Condition
  provide: TrueBlock 
}
```

That would be the whole definition of `If`. No *implementation* required.

Wondering if this is sort of the right approach to this problem. The problem being that you can't really *implement* an `If` statement without resorting to using `If` itself. And so you define it as atomic.

Comment: The main obstacle is perhaps that you're attempting to define the semantics of a syntactic construct in the very same syntax. This fails often. Other examples of this failure include M Spivey's first book on the Z specification language. (Its essence was that everything meant $\bot$ even though that  wasn't intended.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One general rule of Turing completeness is that you need some form of conditional branching built into your model. A Turing machine, for example, can transition to a new state based on what it sees on the tape. Programming-language-wise, a while loop works, as does an infinite loop with a conditional break statement, or if and goto.

As such, if you have no form of conditional branching built into your model already, you can't create one out of nowhere—if your model isn't Turing complete, you'll need to add something else from outside to the model to make it so.

An "atomic" if statement will do the trick, certainly, as will something like Lisp's conditional. But whatever it is, it'll have to be implemented by the compiler or interpreter, rather than being created within the language itself.

Comment: What is the form of conditional branching in the lambda calculus? (Certainly, you need to be able to *mimic* conditional branching to some extent.)

Comment: @DerekElkins I would like to know that too (regarding the Lisp conditional comment).

Comment: @Draconis wondering if there is a name for this sort of property/thing: "whatever it is, it'll have to be implemented by the compiler or interpreter". I have run into this in a few cases and if it had a name it would be easier to understand I think.

Comment: @DerekElkins I'd say that the conditional is `λc:λa:λb:c.a.b`. In other words, apply the Church boolean `c` to `a` and `b`, returning `a` if `c` is true, and `b` if `c` is false.

Comment: @LancePollard I'd call it "fundamental" to the language.

Comment: @LancePollard "primitives" is sometimes used for the basic building blocks of a language, which are implemented at a lower level. (Sometimes, though, a primitive could be implemented in terms of the other ones, so it's slightly different from what you ask.)

Comment: @Draconis And you would call that conditional branching being "built into" the lambda calculus?

Comment: @chi Sometimes you have two or more things that could be primitives, and each could be built in terms of the others. In that case you are free to decide which one is "primitive" and which one is derived.